# How to replace an email domain using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm inputting a $PrimaryOwner email like this and I'm just wondering how can I change the domain to be always China Tenant domain no matter what type of domain I'm passing.

For example:

```
input
john@gmail.com
jame@yahoo.com
sarah@ymail.com

output
john@china.com
jame@china.com
sarah@china.com
```

I'm using replace() like this and it's working fine but this look very redundant so I'm just wondering if there is way to simplify it because I have like over 10+ different domains for my $Primaryowner and $SecondaryOwner.

I thought there would be more simpler version because I'm outputting the same china domain so any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

```
        if ($PrimaryOwner -like "*gmail*") { 
            $PrimaryOwner = $PrimaryOwner.replace("gmail.com", "china.com")
        }
        elseif ($PrimaryOwner -like "*yahoo*") {
            $PrimaryOwner = $PrimaryOwner.replace("yahoo.com", "china.com")
        }
        elseif ($PrimaryOwner -like "*ymail*") {
            $PrimaryOwner = $PrimaryOwner.replace("ymail.com", "china.com")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`MailAddress` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=net-6.0) to parse your addresses:

```
$mails = @(
    'john@gmail.com'
    'jame@yahoo.com'
    'sarah@ymail.com'
)

foreach($mail in $mails) {
    '{0}@china.com' -f ($mail -as [mailaddress]).User
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, really appreciated it. This is very simple and precise.